# Getting Error :- FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm

Whenever I am running my react project in local host by npm start I am getting the below error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoFmK.png)

**Already tried solutions **

After reading lot of solutions online I tried increasing size of cache using

export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=2048 Still same error (also tried for 4,8,16 GB)

Comment: What if you just call node with the option manually? -> `node --max-old-space-size=2048 index.js`?

Comment: module not found error is showing for above command

Comment: Then you don't have a file names `index.js` in that directory, is it called something else?

Comment: I do have index.js in my directory where I am running npm start

Comment: Just try running `node` directly, not `npm start`..